# Delete mySQL table from php link not working (Blank page appears)

Tags: php

I've listed a list of rows from my mySQL database onto an admin page. I now simply want to add an icon beside each row giving the user the option to delete the row in question.

Here's my php delete link:

```
<a href="delete.php?action=delete&id='$id'"><i class="icon-circle-blank"></i></a>
```

And my delete.php file looks like:

```
<?php

require_once 'db.php';
global $con;


    if(($_GET['action'] == 'delete') && isset($_GET['id'])) {

    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $sql = "DELETE FROM quotes WHERE id = '$id'";
    $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

}

header("location: http://localhost:81/logintest/home.php");

    mysqli_close($con);
```

?>

From some reason when I click the link, the page just returns a blank page with no database rows being deleted. What am I overlooking?

Comment: Have you tried `$query = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));`, as well as turning on php error reporting, ie. `ini_set('display_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` to figure out the issue?

Comment: white screen of death: error checking\display are off, turn them on to see the error. at the top of your php page add: `ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); ini_set('html_errors', 0); error_reporting(-1);`

Comment: view your HTML source for your `href`, what does it show you? `var_dump()` also. check for errors on both PHP/SQL.

Comment: really nice injection btw. Hope you won't be going live with this. Someone else will *"make it go boom"* for you.

Comment: How would I be going about in securing this Fred?

Comment: Google "how to prevent SQL injection".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you're showing us a pseudo-code, this will not parse the PHP id variable:

```
delete.php?action=delete&id='$id'
```

you need either:

```
delete.php?action=delete&id=<?= $id ?>
```

or

```
delete.php?action=delete&id=<?php echo $id; ?>
```

Comment: You're right, I didn't parse the PHP id appropriately. I still got a blank screen but my database was being deleted. I've now simply added the header function to redirect back to the admin page

Comment: A sidenote about SQL injection with some links would've been a bonus ;-)

Comment: Haha, @Fred-ii-, I'm actually one of those who doesn't want every MySQL answer flooded with injection warnings or mysql_* functions depreciation warning (with a nice red box) :D

Comment: But on a serious note, this is very dangerous, even a web crawler might cause issues/missing rows.

Comment: @Shomz Yeah I know what you mean. I've been grilled a few times and seeing others get grilled because they don't. Hey... no pressure from me here ;-) as you may have noticed. *Cheers*